# Python subprocess communicating with Powershell and Pipeline Operators

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

I am looking to find the starttime of all chrome instances on my windows computer.  In powershell, I can do this via `get-process chrome | Format-Table StartTime`.

I want to do this in a python script and use the output of this.  My code is below:

```
import subprocess
call = "powershell get-process chrome | powershell Format-Table ProcessName, StartTime"
process = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)
outputs = process.communicate()
print(outputs)
```

The output for this command is `['']`, even with chrome open.

#### Observations

If I change `call` to

```
call = "powershell get-process chrome"
```

this outputs the table, as expected.  I think the error has to do with the pipeline operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150604/45375) is the quickest way to solve your problem based on your approach of implicitly calling *via `cmd.exe`*, due to `shell=True` (`^`-escaping the `|` protects it from up-front interpretation *by `cmd.exe`*)

As also implied by the linked answer, don't use `powershell` *twice*: pass a *single command* that is a *PowerShell* pipeline to a single call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, which implies use of the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter.<sup>[1]</sup>

While **`shell=True` is *convenient*** in terms of syntax (providing a the entire command line as a *single string*), it **isn't *necessary***, and **causes overhead** due to the extra `cmd.exe` process that must be created - let alone the **need for *careful escaping***, to prevent unwanted up-front interpretation of parts of the command line by `cmd.exe`, as in the case at hand.

Therefore, **consider calling `powershell.exe` *directly***, in which case *no* escaping of `|` is needed, but it is then best to **pass the command as an *array***, whose first element is the target *executable*, and whose subsequent elements are the arguments, specified individually:<sup>[2]</sup>

```py
# ...
# Construct the PowerShell CLI call as an *array*:
# The target executable, followed by the arguments to pass to it.
call = "powershell.exe", "-c", "Get-Process chrome | Format-Table ProcessName, StartTime"

# Make the call, but do NOT use `shell=True`
process = subprocess.Popen(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
# ...
```

As an aside:

- The above applies analogously applies to the higher-level [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) function, which - except for advanced use cases such as *asynchronous* execution and providing stdin input *dynamically*, in response to the running process' output - is preferable to the lower-level [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) interface it is based on.

---

<sup>[1] Note that, by contrast, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, now *requires* use of `-Command` / `-c`.</sup>

<sup>[2] On *Windows*, you *may* still pass a single string that is the entire command line (using only `"..."` for *embedded* quoting), but on *Unix*-like platforms using an array is a must in order to pass arguments. (However, in an *argument-less* invocation, the executable name or path may be passed as a string rather than as a one-element array on both platforms. Also, *with `shell=True`* passing a single string even with embedded arguments works on both platforms, as that string becomes a single argument that is passed to the shell executable.)</sup>

Comment: Everyone always says that `shell=True` is bad, but I think you are the first to show me how to remove it without craziness.  Thanks!

Comment: As is often the case, the act of creating a minimal reproducible example of my issue solved the question.  I had written the 95% of the question when I realized my solution, so I posted then posted the answer.  Needless to say, I'm glad I posted as your answer gives me more insight into the nature of the `subprocess` module.  Thanks again.

Comment: Good point, @tripleee - I've changed the wording and have added a second footnote.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the pipeline operator for it to play nice with powershell in subprocess.  Changing `call` to

```
call = "powershell get-process chrome ^| Format-Table ProcessName, StartTime"
```

Solves the issue.